# Rad Gridview ? In asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

in web application, i am using radgridview control, in that i am trying for custom sorting, but i am not getting sorting  please help me thank you. This my code :

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
    PageSize ="3" AllowPaging ="True"  
    Skin="WebBlue" onpageindexchanged="RadGrid1_PageIndexChanged" 
    AllowSorting="True" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" 
    onsortcommand="RadGrid1_SortCommand" >
    <MasterTableView AllowCustomSorting ="true"  >
       <Columns >
         <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText ="Emp No">
            <ItemTemplate >
                 <asp:Label ID="lablemp" runat ="server" Text ='<%# Eval("empno") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
          <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText ="Firstname" SortExpression ="true">               
            <ItemTemplate >
                 <asp:Label ID="lablfname" runat ="server" Text ='<%# Eval("firstname") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
         <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText ="Lastname">
            <ItemTemplate >
                 <asp:Label ID="lablast" runat ="server" Text ='<%# Eval("lastname") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
             <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText ="Sal">
            <ItemTemplate >
                 <asp:Label ID="labsal" runat ="server" Text ='<%# Eval("sal") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
       </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

and this .aspx.cs code:

```
      protected void RadGrid1_SortCommand(object sender, GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridSortExpression expression = new GridSortExpression();
        expression.FieldName = "firstname";
        expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Descending;
        this.RadGrid1.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.AddSortExpression(expression);
        this.RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Rebind();

    }
```

can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should call Rebind() on the Grid as well with **this.RadGrid1.Rebind();**

Regards,
Garfield